# $request->file return null - Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, xampp, laravel-blade

I tried to upload file from a pc to my Laravel application and store to `XAMPP` server. Unfortunately, every time when I want to check the file extension using `$request->file` it always return me null.

But when I tried to debug I have seen that file image name that I uploaded from my system.

Here is code from front end:

```
<form action="{{action('CompaniesSettingController@update', $edit_info->id)}}" method="post",enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="p-image">
    <i class="fa fa-camera upload-button"></i>
    <input class="file-upload" name="company_profile" type="file" id="" accept="image/*"/>
</div>
```

Here Controller code:

```
dd($request->all());  
$filenameWithExt = $request->file('company_profile')->getClientOriginalName();
```

Here is what I got from `dd`

```
array:12 [▼

  "company_profile" => "myimage.jpg"
  "name" => "App Name"
  "email" => "myapp@gmail.com"
  "phone_number" => "12345678"
  "company_overview" => "dfsa"
  "mission" => "dfs"
  "working_evn" => "fgsd"
  "company_ach" => "dfsgdfs"
  "facebook" => "dfsg"
  "linkedin" => "dsf"
  "website" => "sdfsfdg"
 ]
```

As you can see the file that I have uploaded with named `"company_profile" => "myimage.jpg"`. So, I want to get that image name but it return null and also that file image should be stored in my application and file name I will store in database.

Comment: dd($request->company_profile); it should have file name

Comment: instead <form> tag that you wrote manually, i recommend using Form Helper
Form::open([ 'url'=>action('CompaniesSettingController@update', $edit_info->id), 'files'=>true ])   . This will also add a hidden _token for your form

Answer (score 1):

Remove the **comma** after the `method="post"` attribute and add space.

Change this line:

```
<form action="{{action('CompaniesSettingController@update', $edit_info->id)}}" method="post",enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

to

```
<form action="{{action('CompaniesSettingController@update', $edit_info->id)}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And then check the `dd($request->all())` to ensure that it is not the string against company_profile.